# Run ipython notebook with django-extensions

Tags: python, django, ipython, jupyter-notebook, django-extensions

I installed django-extensions and ipython with pip install. Both of them work separately.

However, when I run:

```
python manage.py shell_plus --notebook
```

I got:

```
[C 15:35:20.267 NotebookApp] Bad config encountered during initialization:
[C 15:35:20.267 NotebookApp] Unrecognized flag: '--ext'
```

I used everything by default, nothing changed at all. Did I do something wrong?

BTW: my django project is installed in virtualenv.

Comment: see also: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/7913

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

The django-extensions doesn't work with ipython 3.0, changed it to 2.4 solve the problem.